# How to automate the updating of files if files are modified using bash and git?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

**The scenario:**
User wants to keep a repository on a server, weather it be Github or just any server which has Git installed, with all his dotfiles which he can upload his changes to which he makes to his dotfiles on his local machine. And he wants it to be automated so that every Nth day a job starts to check if his local dotfiles have been modified and if so the modifications get committed and pushed up to the server which contains the dotfile repository. The user keeps a local git repository under a home folder called .dotfiles/ and symlinks his dotfiles to the files under .dotfiles/.

Also, when the user sets up a new operating system he wants to fetch those same dotfiles from the server for his new OS.

**The problem:**
User knows some bash programming, some general programming and some Git commands, but has no clue how to implement such a thing like this.

**The question:**
How does one create a thing like this?

**EDIT:**

Lets narrow this down.

How do I do automation in the shell. A job which happens every Nth day? I can handle the Git part an all that. I just need to know how to start a job automatically in the shell.

F.ex.  job starts every Nth day to check for a given condition. I my case if the date of any of my dotfiles is newer than the date of the files in my local repo. If date is newer then the job runs a script which I write which handles the updating of everything. I know how to write the script for handling the updating of my files, I just don't know how to do this automation to check for the condition.

How do you do the automation?

Comment: This is quite a broad question, making it a poor fit under stack overflow's guidelines. The only answers it encourages are ones which require "gib me da codez" or snarky ones. If you're looking for a conversation rather than a specific question, you would be better off finding a forum to post on.

Comment: Alright let me refractor my question. One minute...

Comment: The edit changes your question drastically, so much that nothing in your question pertaining to git is relevant or necessary and in the interest of "keep it simple", about 90% of your question should be removed! More importantly for SO, your question is actually not related to programming now and should be posted at http://superuser.com/ instead. However, to get you able to solve this on your own if you wish, seek out _crontab_  information; http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/ may help.

Comment: create a cron task, which will run a script, controlling the specified git repo state.

Comment: instead of comparing modification dates why not just use git to check for changes. `git status --porcelain`, for example, could be easily parsed by your script. I wouldn't recommend automating stuff like `git add` and `git commit` though.

Comment: @desbo why wouldn't you automate `git add` and `git commit`? i even keep my `/etc` unter automatic VCS-control using [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/) (this doesn't do a automatic push though)

Comment: @umläute depends on how much is automated I suppose, but I'd want to be able to specify which files are added, and the message. I may have misinterpreted the question but it seemed like the OP wanted to automate everything, which could make for poorly structured commits

Comment: Thank you guys. Didn't know what a cron job was and now I know that and after googling around on how to create a cron job it turns out to be as easy as 1,2,3... Thank you. Now it's just to write the script and have the cron thing call it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: I want to do something I don't know how to do. 
The question: How do I do it?

I think you should look at cron (or incron) or something :)

Comment: Didn't know what cron jobs meant, and now I know, and googled around how to create a cron job in Linux and it turns out to be easy as a pie. So now I write the script that checks for a condition and executes something if a certain condition is met. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Yes, cron is pretty simple, but really useful.